# Error when trying to pop KV pair from dictionary in loop

Tags: python, dictionary, del

I have a dictionary that looks like so:

```
{'1A': {'White Bread loaf large': 1, 'Brown Bread loaf large': 1, 'Skimmed Milk Pint': 1, 'Cheddar Cheese Medium 300g': 1, 'Tomatoes Fresh Vine 500g': 1, 'Carrots 1Kg': 1, 'Potatoes 600g': 1, 'Bacon 300g': 1, 'Eggs Free Range Medium 12': 1, 'Ham 300g': 1, 'Frozen Peas 800g': 1, 'Kitchen Roll 200 Sheets': 1}, 
'1B': {'Brown Bread loaf large': 1, 'Bread Sliced White large': 1, 'Skimmed Milk Pint': 1, 'Cheddar Cheese Mature 300g': 1, 'Tomatoes Plum Can 500g': 1, 'Carrots 1Kg': 1, 'Potatoes 600g': 1, 'Rice White 500g': 1, 'Rice Brown 500g': 1, 'Butter 500g': 1, 'Bacon 300g': 1, 'Ham 300g': 1, 'Frozen Peas 800g': 1, 'Fresh onions 300g': 1, 'Tea Bags 50 pack': 1},...
```

I am trying to remove all KV pairs where to key is equal to 'Rice Brown 500g'.

this is how I am trying to do it:

```
for i in list(my_dict):
    for n in my_dict[i]:
        if n == 'Rice Brown 500g':
            my_dict.pop(n)
```

I also tried using `del my_dict[n]`

I keep receiving this error: **KeyError: 'Rice Brown 500g'**

I am out of ideas in what else to try. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a simpler, more pythonic way, to iterate over the sub-dictionaries inside your main dictionary:

```
for v in my_dict.values():
    v.pop('Rice Brown 500g', None)
```

This does the trick, each v is one of the sub-directories, and the 2nd parameter to pop() prevents a KeyError.

Comment: @KellyBundy: you're right, replaced items() with values()

Answer (score -1):

There is no key `'Rice Brown 500g'` in your dictionary, there are keys `'1A', '1B'`. So, iterate over them, get nested dictionaries and remove from them that values:

```
my_dict = {'1A': {'White Bread loaf large': 1, 'Brown Bread loaf large': 1, 'Skimmed Milk Pint': 1, 'Cheddar Cheese Medium 300g': 1, 'Tomatoes Fresh Vine 500g': 1, 'Carrots 1Kg': 1, 'Potatoes 600g': 1, 'Bacon 300g': 1, 'Eggs Free Range Medium 12': 1, 'Ham 300g': 1, 'Frozen Peas 800g': 1, 'Kitchen Roll 200 Sheets': 1}, 
'1B': {'Brown Bread loaf large': 1, 'Bread Sliced White large': 1, 'Skimmed Milk Pint': 1, 'Cheddar Cheese Mature 300g': 1, 'Tomatoes Plum Can 500g': 1, 'Carrots 1Kg': 1, 'Potatoes 600g': 1, 'Rice White 500g': 1, 'Rice Brown 500g': 1, 'Butter 500g': 1, 'Bacon 300g': 1, 'Ham 300g': 1, 'Frozen Peas 800g': 1, 'Fresh onions 300g': 1, 'Tea Bags 50 pack': 1}}
for i in list(my_dict):
    for key in my_dict[i]:
        for list_2 in list(key):
            for key_2 in list_2:
               if key_2 == 'Rice Brown 500g':
                list_2.pop(key_2)

print(my_dict)
```

```
{'1A': {'White Bread loaf large': 1, 'Brown Bread loaf large': 1, 'Skimmed Milk Pint': 1, 'Cheddar Cheese Medium 300g': 1, 'Tomatoes Fresh Vine 500g': 1, 'Carrots 1Kg': 1, 'Potatoes 600g': 1, 'Bacon 300g': 1, 'Eggs Free Range Medium 12': 1, 'Ham 300g': 1, 'Frozen Peas 800g': 1, 'Kitchen Roll 200 Sheets': 1}, '1B': {'Brown Bread loaf large': 1, 'Bread Sliced White large': 1, 'Skimmed Milk Pint': 1, 'Cheddar Cheese Mature 300g': 1, 'Tomatoes Plum Can 500g': 1, 'Carrots 1Kg': 1, 'Potatoes 600g': 1, 'Rice White 500g': 1, 'Rice Brown 500g': 1, 'Butter 500g': 1, 'Bacon 300g': 1, 'Ham 300g': 1, 'Frozen Peas 800g': 1, 'Fresh onions 300g': 1, 'Tea Bags 50 pack': 1}}
```